# JointJs Cycle Detection

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I am trying to implement an algorithm to detect cycles in a directed graph (only outbound connections) using JointJS. I have written the following code which does not perform expectedly.

```
        var _elements = graph.getElements();
        var visited = [];
        var level = 0;
        var isCycleExists;
        for (var i = 0; i < _elements.length; i++) {
            var elem = _elements[i];
            //only checking nodes which do have predecessors
            if ((graph.getPredecessors(elem).length > 0) && !elem.isLink()
                    && hasCycle(elem, visited, level)) {
                isCycleExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

     function hasCycle(comp, visited, level) {
        var successors = graph.getSuccessors(comp);
        visited.push(comp.id);
        for (var i = 0; i < successors.length; i++) {
            var c = successors[i];
            var _successors = graph.getSuccessors(c);
            if (_successors.length == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (visited.indexOf(c.id) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
            visited.push(c.id);
            if (hasCycle(c, visited.slice(), ++level)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It would be really helpful if anyone could help me in this.

Comment: So what is expected behaviour and what is actual behaviour which differs from the expected one? Also, you got `}` missing, is it just a copying mistake or you got it in your code and it causes errors?

Comment: A----->B------>C------>D------>E : This is a pretty linear structure but still according to my program, it shows that it has a cycle. I have also tried with many other structures which actually had loops and if I remove the cycles from those structures, it works but in the aforementioned use case it failed.

The } is just a copying error. Please ignore that.

For your information, I have also tried with the following:

A---->B
C----->D
A----->D
C------>B
B------>D
D------->B
In this case my programs shows the existence of cycle in this graph structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is successor is not the same as direct successor. Check out `graph.getSuccessors(comp)` value: if the lib uses consistent function names, that should contain B,C,D and E for the first run. So you mark those visited, but also run `hasCycle(c, visited.slice(), ++level)` where you are checking nodes starting from D again (I guess D is the first one for which you get the "already visited" case).

First, I'd recommend to get rid of doubling the iteration in your function, do smth like

```
 function hasCycle(comp, visited, level) {
    var successors = graph.getSuccessors(comp), i;

    if (visited.indexOf(comp.id) > -1)
        return true;
    visited.push(comp.id);

    for (i = 0; i < successors.length; i++)
        if (hasCycle(successors[i], visited.slice(), ++level))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

And second, more importantly, try the [`graph.getNeighbors`](https://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Graph:getNeighbors) method instead of `graph.getSuccessors` (remember to check only neighbors in one direction).

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I have tried this modified hasCycle() method and it is so far working for the graphs I tested. Only a small minor typo mistake in the 2nd line - an existence of **i**. I would keep you posted here in case I find something interesting in executing this algorithm.

Comment: @AmitKumarMondal `i` in the second line is by intent. You may put variables in a comma-separated way: `var a = ..., b = ...;` or define separately `var a = ...; var b = ...;` and put `var b` into a `for`-expression, but this is all the same. It's just a matter of code style.

Comment: I tried with the following: 
`var successors = graph.getNeighbors(comp, {
   'opt.outbound' : true
  });`
This actually failed in the scenario I mentioned previously in which my previous algorithm also failed. According to JointJS API, `getNeighbors()` must have been the real method one should use but it didn't work for me in this scenario.

Comment: @AmitKumarMondal I guess it's just `var successors = graph.getNeighbors(comp, { outbound : true });`. `opt` is a name of the object param.

Comment: My bad!! I tried with `var neighbors = graph.getNeighbors(comp, { outbound : true }), i;` and it is working as expected. Actually I thought of trying this as your previous solution failed in a graph which is linear and I refreshed the page and tried your previous solution on the same graph in which it failed. But it worked. I don't know why. But it was pretty strange. That's why I thought of giving the `getNeighbors()` a try to check and it is working as expected. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I tried the new algorithm with `getNeighbors()` and it failed in the following scenario : `A--->B, A--->C, C--->D, D--->B`. This is a linear structure with an added path. Even if I try this, it fails : `A--->B, A--->C and C--->B`.

Comment: I have also tried these graphs with `getSuccessors()` as well and it fails too.

Comment: @AmitKumarMondal well, may be you should ask a new question after some thorough testing and show there your current code and when it fails. And/or create a jsFiddle which may help to explore your issue further since now it sounds more specific while my answer was only about an algorithm (and I haven't actually tested the code)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the root cause for such erratic behavior using this algorithm.

Actually JointJS API method `getElements()` returns the array of elements in the order of entry in the graph cells. That means if you create 3 elements `A, B, C` to create a graph like `A-->B-->C` but you have added these elements in the order `A` first, `C` second and `B` at the end. Now according to the if condition `(graph.getPredecessors(elem).length > 0) && !elem.isLink() && hasCycle(elem, visited, level)`, the cycle detection actually starts from `C`. In this scenario, `C` doesn't have any outbound neighbor and it is marked as visited. Now, in the next iteration, `B` is checked (as it is entered into the Graph after `C`) and it has `C` as its outbound neighbor. Now `C` is again evaluated but `C` is already marked as visited. Hence, it shows existence of a loop.

So, I believe, our search in a graph should be started from the nodes which doesn't have any predecessors. For instance, in the previous example, our search must begin always with `A`. The graph also might contain one or several nodes which don't have any predecessor. In this scenario as well, we need to start our search from the nodes which don't have any predecessor. For instance, `A1-->B, A1-->C, A2-->B, A2-->C` like this. Our detection must begin from `A1` and `A2`.

I have modified the methods as follows which conforms to the previous strategy:

```
function checkForCycleExistence() {
    var visited = [];
    var level = 0;
    var isCycleExists;
    var _elements = graph.getElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < _elements.length; i++) {
        var elem = _elements[i];
        if ((graph.getPredecessors(elem).length == 0)
                && hasCycle(elem, visited, level)) {
            isCycleExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isCycleExists) {
        console.log("Cycle Exists");
    }
    return isCycleExists;
}

function hasCycle(comp, visited, level) {
    var neighbors = graph.getNeighbors(comp, {
        outbound : true
    }), i;

    if (visited.indexOf(comp.id) > -1)
        return true;

    visited.push(comp.id);

    for (i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++)
        if (hasCycle(neighbors[i], visited.slice(), ++level))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```